# Dynamically edit nested PHP object attributes

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have an array `array(container, article, title)` and a value `"Hello, is it me you're looking for?"`

Now I want to set the attribute of a given object `$target`.

Now, what I want to happen is:

```
//from
$levels = array(container, article, title);
$target->container->article->title = 'Hello World';

// logic
changeAttribute($target, $levels, "Hello, is it me you're looking for?");

//to
echo $target->container->article->title; // 'Hello, is it me you're looking for?';
```

Is this any way possible? Thanks!

Comment: Whats your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
function changeAttribute(&$target, $levels, $value) {
    $current = $target;
    foreach($levels as $key) {
      $current =& $current->$key;
    }
    $current = $value;
}
```